# QT SDK MySQL nmake error

Tags: qt, qmake, nmake, qtsql

I'm trying to build the QMYSQL plugin for the QT SDK and upon executing qmake (ran successfully) -using the MySQL win32 files I had placed into C:- I tried to run nmake and got the following errors:

```
rc is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file -I guess it refers to the qsqlmysqld_resource.rc file here-

NMAKE: fatal error U1077: 'rc': return code 0x1
Stop.

NMAKE: fatal error U1077: C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe return code 0x2
Stop.
```

What may be the cause for this?

Comment: AFAIK `rc.exe` tool is provided by the Windows SDK. There's a possibly related question at [su]: [rc.exe from windows sdk missing](http://superuser.com/questions/119867/rc-exe-from-windows-sdk-missing).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that VC is not correctly configured
Please run **vcvars32.bat** in **C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC** folder

See more by links
[qt faq](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/3.12.3/html/faq/Problems-Getting-Started.html) and [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4d2c09s.aspx)